# Delete Everything(the rest of the text) after a specific string

Tags: notepad++

How can i delete Everything after a string like 'gnirts'. this might give you a better understanding:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMjPW.png)

[and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Y6T.png)

Comment: Please copy/paste the text before and after instead of using pictures, so we can test our solutions before posting them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Using find and replace:

1. Hit CTRL-H to open the Replace dialogue box
2. enter gnirts.* into `Find what`
3. leave `Replace with` empty
4. Select `Regular expression` and `.matches newline`
5. Click on `Replace`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you help me on this? Find what:`,--#TDA:IN_SOURCE*RAISE; 
 
end;,` Replace with:`,,` but it's not happening. I want to replace everything that comes in between `,,` with specific text I mentioned above.

Comment: Using regular expression option: Find: ,.*,  Replace with: ,,

Comment: `,--#TDA:IN_SOURCE.*?RAISE; end;,` This worked for me!Thanks